# React native iOS arrow keys

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

[image]

I have a page with multiple inputs, is it possible to add those arrow keys button to the keyboard from React native,

so the user can use arrow keys to move between fields.

FYI, I have the same page built in responsive web as well, and it has those arrow keys working prefectly inside the iPhone Chrome browser. Ideally I want to show the arrow keys in the app as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution, trying it now, hopefully it works https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-accessory

Answer (score 1):

For this, we are using react-native-keyboard-accessory:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-accessory.

Unfourtunately, we need to hook up the next and prev key events manually.